# How to set parallax layout as my layered live wallpaper which moved with device acceleration?

Tags: android, 3d, parallax, live-wallpaper, layered

```
private ParallaxLayerLayout parallaxLayout;
private SensorTranslationUpdater translationUpdater;

translationUpdater = new SensorTranslationUpdater(this);
parallaxLayout.setTranslationUpdater(translationUpdater);

translationUpdater.registerSensorManager();
```

I want to set parallax layout as my Live wallpaper.
Here I mentioned above code for set multiple image layers for parallax layout and its working completely in activity, but now how to set it as a live wallpaper.